# Placing links to own site in templates?

Tags: seo

I wonder if its good or bad to put links to your own site when u design a theme eg. in Tumblr? I noticed this when i saw many links to my site from people's tumblr using my templates.

Maybe i should use nofollow on those links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible drawbacks can be immense. If a dodgy site links to you (even by the design footer) then it can result in trouble for your domain. Adding nofollow doesn't really solve this.

If a third party site hosts your template (there are several "theme" sites) you can add a direct link to a hosted version of your template on that site (direct link within your template) and let the theme site link to your site.

In terms of user experience, instead of just having your template they'll now have a choice (not a captive market as some may hope for, but better from the users perspective). Search engines will not penalise you for scam pages adopting your template and you still get link juice (albeit somewhat diluted).

Comment: Oh ... I guess I need to un-link all my templates. I nv thought of this at first... until i saw Google Analytics. Haha, I was shocked at the number of links I have ...

Comment: Its something to be applauded (having a popular theme), well done.

Comment: Getting links from dodgy sites doesn't really do you any harm. In reality you can't control who links to you.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - true to an extent, but if 99% of links towards your domain are from unscrupulous sources it sets off alarm bells

Answer (score 1):

Theres also the issue of anchor text. If your template has a link back to your site with the text 'Swedish Massage Reviews', you're going to have a lot of incoming links with identical anchor text, which *on its own* can look unnatural.